# Using the concept of $G_\delta$ sets, show that the union of two measurable sets is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu: $ outer measure.
Given the fact that if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are measurable then for $G_\delta$ sets $G_1$ that contains $A_1$ and $G_2$ that contains $A_2$, we have $\mu(G_1 - A_1)=0$ and $\mu(G_2-A_2)=0$.
I want to show that $\exists G$, a $G_\delta$ set such that $\mu(G - (A_1 \cup A_2))=0$.

Can I start of with supposing $G=G_1\cup G_2$. Since each of $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains $A_1, A_2$, respectively, then $G$ should also contain both $A_1$ and  $A_2$, which implies that $A_1 \cup A_2 \subset G$.
Hence, 
        $\mu(G-(A_1\cup A_2))=\mu((G-A_1)\cap(G-A_2))=\mu(G-A_1)+\mu(G-A_2)$ since both are zeros thus $A_1\cup A_2$ is measurable.

Comment: By definition, the countable union of measurable sets are measurable. You might want to rephrase your question title to make it a bit more clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Math1000 That depends. If measurability is defined a la Caratheodory, then closure under countable unions is nontrivial.

Comment: @Math1000 would like to show that there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ that contains the $A_1\cup A_2$ and that $\mu(G-(A_1\cup A_2))=0$

Comment: The last two lines: why $\mu$ of the intersection is equal to the sum and why "both are zeros"?

Comment: @A.G. that is the thing that is confusing me because I couldn't make it out either. but I assumed that since $G=G_1\cup G_2$, then $G$ is also a $G_\delta set$ that contains both $A_1$ and $A_2$. Hence the measure of addend in the last line is both zero

Comment: It does not look right. The intersection can be small, but, for example, $G-A_1=(G_1-A_1)\cup(G_2-A_1)$ where the former has $\mu=0$ and the latter can be large.

Comment: @A.G. then how does one show that the union of two measurable set given the concept of $G_\delta$ because as what I understand, if a measureable set A is contained in a $G_\delta$ set G, then $\mu(G-A)=0.$

Comment: @desperatemuch Not for *all* $G$, but for *some* $G$, i.e. there *exists* a $G_\delta$ set $G$ with $\mu(G-A)=0$. But there exist many others where $\mu>0$. For example, the whole space $X$ is trivially a $G_\delta$ set, but $\mu(X-A)\ne 0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree. But that is not clear from the title. Further, I am accustomed to the notation $\mu^*$ for an outer measure, and $\mu$ the measure obtained by restriction of $\mu^*$ to $\mu^*$-measurable sets, a la Carathéodory, so there is further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: $G - (A \cup B)=(G_1 \cup G_2) - (A \cup B)$
 $=(G_1 \cup G_2) \cap A^C \cap B^C$
  $= [(G_1 \cup G_2) \cap A^C] \cap B^C$
   $=[(G_1 \cap A^C) \cup (G_2 \cap A^C)] \cap B^C$
    $=[(G_1 \cap A^C) \cap B^C] \cup [(G_2 \cap A^C) \cap B^C]$
    $\subseteq (G_1 - A) \cup (G_2 - B)$

Answer (score 0):

You can work out the last two lines like the following: prove first that
$$
G-(A_1\cup A_2)=(G_1-(A_1\cup A_2))\cup(G_2-(A_1\cup A_2))
$$
and then do the estimate
\begin{align}
\mu(G-(A_1\cup A_2))&=\mu((G_1-(A_1\cup A_2))\cup(G_2-(A_1\cup A_2)))\le \\
&\le \mu(G_1-(A_1\cup A_2))+\mu(G_2-(A_1\cup A_2))\le\\
&\le \mu(G_1-A_1)+\mu(G_2-A_2)=0+0=0
\end{align}
where in the first inequality you use the *subadditivity* and in the second one the *monotonicity* of the outer measure $\mu$ (since $G_k-(A_1\cup A_2)\subset G_k-A_k$).